MySQL 8 no me deja hacer un UNION
Normalmente trabajo con MySQL 5.5 y esta vez me toco pasar la BD a MySQL 8 y me dio algunos problemas, uno de ellos es:
No puedo hacer esto
SELECT 0 idBanco, '-SIN BANCO-' Banco 
   FROM bancos LIMIT 1
UNION ALL
SELECT idBanco, Banco 
   FROM bancos

MySQL 8 me da error, ¿alguien sabe porque?

Hola Roberto, sería bueno si pudieras agregar el mensaje de error. Pulsa [edit] para agregarlo en tu pregunta.

Según el manual de MySQL, en la v8.0+ UNION ha sido refactorizado y las expresiones como las que tiene tu consulta deben estar en paréntesis, leer al respecto.
(SELECT 0 idBanco, '-SIN BANCO-' Banco 
   FROM bancos LIMIT 1)
UNION ALL
SELECT idBanco, Banco 
   FROM bancos

Sin embargo, la primera parte de la consulta es constante, no es necesario vincularla a una tabla, entonces se podría escribir como:
SELECT 0 idBanco, '-SIN BANCO-' Banco 
UNION ALL
SELECT idBanco, Banco 
   FROM bancos


PD. En el caso de MariaDB 10.4+, la consulta original no da error, pero en el resultado todas las filas son 0, -SIN BANCO-. Se arregla de igual manera que lo descrito para MySQL.
